# How do I add pavement marking to a roundabout model

Tags: texturing

I have imported a DXF 3d model of a roundabout. I applied a texture to the surface for asphalt (asphalt part only). I did not UV unwrap. I rendered a very high resolution (16000 px wide) ortho image of the asphalt. In photoshop I painted the white and yellow striping on a black background registered to the asphalt image. I saved as a jpeg for use in blender. Can you help with using that texture map as an overlay onto the asphalt texture in Blender?

Terrainman

Comment: You can use the [mix node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html) but you need add a UV Map to your model and unwarp it if you want use image texture in  a complex mesh like a roundabout.

Comment: I tried using a UV unwrap but had trouble aligning the stripes with each other where the UV unwrap broke it into pieces. If anyone has another method of pavement stripes and marking for roundabouts and intersections please let me know